# Theorem 4.2.24 in Liu: openess of the set of regular points

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I trie to understand the proof of theorem 4.2.24 in Liu:

Let $X$ be an algebraic variety over an algebraic closed field $k$. Then the set of regular point $\operatorname{Reg}(X)$ is an open subset of $X$.

My problem come in the beginning of the proof:

The author says that we can suppose that $X$ is integral: I dont understand.

I explain: he says that the regular points are integral (ok, a previous result) and the set of integral point is open (ok, previous result) but for me it is not enough. It seems to me that we can so assume that all the points of $X$ are integral wich is not equivalent with $X$ integral (for me it is: reduced and irreducible). I know that $X$ integral imply that all the point are integral but I don't know the inverse.

Comment: Dear Gabriel, Regarding the reduction to the integral case, try thinking about a simple example, such as two lines crossing (the set $xy = 0$ in the plane), to see how the reduction step works in that case.  Regards,

Comment: @ Matt E: thanks. In fact it seems that a scheme $X$ is integral iff for all $x\in X$, the local ring $\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$ is integral. Correct?

Comment: Dear Gabriel, Not quite, because a disjoint union of integral schemes has this property. It should be a pleasant exercise for you to prove that for a Noetherian scheme, having integral local rings is in fact equivalent to being a finite disjoint union of integral schemes.  Regards,

Comment: I thought I have found. What's wrong: one can suppose that $X=\operatorname{Spec}A$ because a scheme is integral iff $\mathcal{O}_X(U)$ is integral for all $U$ affine. Then if $A$ is not integral let $x,y\neq0$ such that $xy=0$. As $x\neq 0$ there exist $\mathfrak{p}$ such that $x\neq0$ in $A_\mathfrak{p}$. But we have still $xy=0$ in $A_\mathfrak{p}$ and so $A_\mathfrak{p}$ is not integral.

Comment: Dear Gabriel, As I already pointed out, your statement can't be true, since a disjoint union of more than one integral schemes is obviously not integral, but the local rings obviously are integral.  So the natural thing to do is to see what happens in your argument when you try to apply it to this case: what you'll find is that either $x$ or $y$ vanishes in each $A_{\mathfrak p}$. Regards,

Comment: Oh yes I see my stupid mistake. I think about the argument of disjoint union

Comment: Thanks. I think I have found (except other stupid mistakes...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I want to proove that one can suppose that $X$ is integral.

First the irreducible components are disjoints: if $\mathfrak{n}\in V(\mathfrak{p})\cap V(\mathfrak{q})$ where $V(\mathfrak{p})$ and $V(\mathfrak{q})$ are irreducible maximal ie $\mathfrak{p}$ et $\mathfrak{q}$ minimal then $\mathfrak{p}$ and $\mathfrak q$ are minimal ideals is $A_\mathfrak{n}$ wich is integral hence has a unique minimal ideal $(0)$ so $\mathfrak{p}=\mathfrak{q}$.

Secondly: each irreducible component $K$ is open because the complement of the other irreducible component hence for all $x\in K$, $\mathcal{O}_{K,x}=\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$ is integral. So $K$ is reduced and irreducible so integral.

By considering the irreducible component one can so suppose that $X$ is integral.